# C# - list of all textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a code in C++ where txtControls is of type  std::vector txtControls;

```
for(int i=0;i<txtControls.size();++i)
{
  if(txtControls[i]->GetValue() != "")
  {
    if(watermarkCheckControls[i]->IsChecked())
      xml += "<field display='yes' ";
    else
      xml += "<field display='no' ";
  }
}
```

I also want to check if the textbox is not empty/null.
I want to achieve the same functionality in C# i have various textboxes in Windows forms app

Comment: Omit the C++ part and specify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the form, after the call of InitializeControls() fill a custom array with them:

```
TextBox[] myTextBoxes = new TextBox[] {this.xxxx, this. yyyy}
```

You can, of course, create the array at class level.

What you cannot is to fill the array at design time using the IDE and control properties (as far as I know).

Comment: and how do i check if the textbox is not emptied using what you cited

Comment: Are you talking about textboxes with no text inside or about null references?

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextBoxes[i].Text));

Comment: @MikeMarynowski: The `Text` property is never null.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: are you sure? What happens if you do myTextBox[i].Text = null?

Comment: @SoMoS: It returns `String.Empty`.

Comment: That's still the recommended approach to check for an empty string. You can check .Length == 0 if you like, doesn't particularly matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtControls.Length; i++) {
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtControls[i].Text)) {
       // do something now that you know the text isn't null, empty string, or white space.
   }
}
```